# Pipe last 11 characters in filename to a text file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, permutation

- Have a directory full of file names that end with .mp3 and have a code in it that i would like to pipe into a text file.

I need to get the last 11 characters before the .mp3 part of a file in a certain directory and pipe that into a text file (with bash on mac osx)

How do I accomplish this? With sed?

Comment: I do not have significant rep to upvote answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a list of files with names like "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.mp3" and want to extract "pqrstuvwxyz". You can do this directly in bash without invoking any fancy `sed` business:

`for F in *.mp3; do STRIP=${F/.mp3}; echo ${STRIP: -11}; done > list.txt`

The first `STRIP` variable is the name of each file `F` with the `.mp3` extension removed. Then you echo the last 11 characters and save to a file.

There's a nice page on bash substitutions [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). `sed` is great but I personally find it's overkill for these simple cases.

Comment: It can be done with `${mavar: -15:11}`, and it worth mentioning that it's from Bash 4.2.

Comment: Good call. I was actually playing with to see if I could reduce it to a single substitution and avoid the temporary variable. I don't think it can get more straightforward than that!

Comment: Wow! you guys sure do know a lot about bash! :) thanks!

Comment: Don't use all upper case for non-exported variable names and always quote your variables (google is your friend). `for f in *.mp3; do strip="${f/.mp3}"; echo "${strip: -11}"; done > list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Along with good above answers, can be done via awk

```
for f in `ls *.mp3`;
echo  $f|awk -F. '{printf substr($1,length($1)-11,length($1)),$2;}'
done
```